# Notification image not showing on some devices like Vivo

Tags: flutter, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, localnotification

I am using FCM and Flutter Local Notification's plugin for displaying notifications. The problem is that the big image in the notification is not visible on all devices, like Vivo. Only the title and body is visible.

Any fix for this?

[image]